# Check Hall Booking status

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014

I'm making a Hall Booking System, and I've being struggling with the Booking Module

I have 2 tables `Halls` & `Bookings`

*Halls table With Sample Data*

```
id   hallName   hallType  numSeats  status
---------------------------------------------
1   Hall 1      Normal    500       active
2   Hall 2      VIP       30        active
3   Hall 3      VVIP      5         active
4   Hall 4      Normal    60        active
5   Hall 5      Normal    80        active
6   Hall 4+5    Normal    140       active
```

*Booking Table with Sample Data*

```
id custId hallId beginDate    endDate    time        status
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1   1     1      2022-09-26   2022-09-26  morning     confirmed
2   6     4      2022-09-26   2022-09-26  evening     cancelled
3   4     3      2022-09-26   2022-09-26  full time   pending
4   9     4      2022-09-26   2022-09-30  after noon  confirmed
```

Booking time slots are "morning",  "after noon", "evening" &  "full time"

I have being trying on the Booking validations as well as a report that shows Halls booking status

**Edit**

After suggestions in the comments I have edited and removed the second part, maybe will post seperately if I can't figure out

Here is what I want to be the result

The records can be filtered by endDate(e.g 2022-09-26)

if Booking exists which is not cancelled for the provided beginDate, the time slot should be labelled as `Booked`

if a booking does not exist for the provided beginDate or its canclled, the time slot should be labeled as `Available`

If  a `full time` Booking slot ecists for the provied beginDate, all the time the 3 slots should be labeled as `Booked`

Here is the twist that may complicate things

As you can see from the `Halls table`, Hall 6 is a combination of Halls 4 & 5 which means if any of them is booked, Hall 6 should be marked as `unavailable` or even `Booked` will be fine.

Overall, here is a sample result based on the above booking table

```
 hallName   hallType  morning   after noon   evening
------------------------------------------------------
hall 1     Normal    Booked      available    available
hall 2     VIP       available   available    available
hall 3     VVIP      Booked      Booked       Booked
hall 4     Normal    available   Booked       available
hall 5     Normal    available   available    available
hall 6     Normal    available   unavailable  available
```

if we take the `Booking` Table with Sample data, the result should be as shown above

I'm not that much familiar with Joins, merges, etc which are what I'm thinking the solution is. I tried merge with When matched and when Not matched but could not figure it out to work

I then tried left joining the Halls table to the Booking table seems to be the closest so far and the output is clear.

```
DECLARE @date NVarchar(50) = '2022-09-26'
SELECT h.id, h.hallName, h.hallType, b.time FROM Halls h LEFT JOIN 
        Bookings b ON b.hallId=h.id WHERE b.beginDate=@date
```

this returns only Booked halls with beginDate of that

If I drop the `WHERE` clause, all the 6 halls are returned but time slots which aren't booked are returned as `NULL`

btw I'm working on the last module and at firts I was working with a single check in date and requirement changed into Range `beginDate` & `endDate` & that is when problems arose.

Comment: You may ask one question per post here, which is used up by your *part one*.,  Your *part two* needs to be in a separate post, as it is a separate question.

Comment: They're reality related and share the logic, so I though putting them in one, but it doesn't mean to answer them both, I'm just trying to get help

Comment: Doesn't matter. They're different questions. They need to be in separate posts. SO is a question and answer site - note that **question** is singular, not plural. It's not a *numbered list of questions* site. See the [help] pages for more information about how the site works.

Comment: @Abdifatah i believe you need to elaborate more on your first question. i mean, does `cancelled` affect the result in someway? to be honest, even the first question will produce quite the query. further more, we haven't seen any of your attempt. keep in mind that stackoverflow is not a free code generator.

Comment: I have edited it again and removed the secod question. I know the logic is same just with a little twist. The whole thing was working fine befere  The Booking changed into Range date and I was not aware of Hall 6 scenarior before

Comment: Is there any columns in your table that is able to identify that `Hall 6` is a combine of other halls ?

Comment: The Table scheme is as shown,  @BagusTesa talked about Normalization, should I create a second table for Hall 6 or there's other way to get around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to fix your design how are you intend to store information that `Hall 6` is a combine of `Hall 4 + 5`

One simple way is to add another column in the `Halls` table that indicate that. Example

```
create table Halls
(
  id int,
  hallName varchar(10),   
  hallType varchar(10),  
  numSeats int,
  status varchar(10),
  combine_id int
);

insert into Halls values
(4,   'Hall 4',      'Normal',     60,       'active', 6),
(5,   'Hall 5',      'Normal',     80,       'active', 6),
(6,   'Hall 4+5',    'Normal',    140,       'active', null);
```

Once that is in-placed, you need to translate the `Bookings` to handle the combined Halls. This is perform by the CTE `BookingData`. It will create row for `Hall 6` if `Hall 4` or `Hall 5` is `pending` or `confirmed`. And simiarly the other way round. When `Hall 6` is `Booked`, `Hall 4` and `Hall 5` will be unavailable.

After that it is just simple pivoting of data

The solution:

```
DECLARE @date date = '2022-09-26';

with BookingData as
(
  select b.hallId, b.time, b.status, beginDate
  from   Bookings b
  
  union all
  
  select hallId = h.combine_id, b.time, 
         status = case when b.status in ('pending', 'confirmed')
                       then 'unavailable'
                       else 'available'
                       end, 
         beginDate
  from   Bookings b
         inner join Halls h on b.hallId = h.id
  where  h.combine_id is not null
  
  union all
  
  select hallId = h.id, b.time, 
         status = case when b.status in ('pending', 'confirmed')
                       then 'unavailable'
                       else 'available'
                       end,   
         beginDate
  from   Bookings b
       inner join Halls h on b.hallId = h.combine_id
  where  h.combine_id is not null
)
SELECT  id, 
        hallName, 
        hallType, 
        [morning]   = isnull([morning], 'available'), 
        [afternoon] = isnull([afternoon], 'available'), 
        [evening]   = isnull([evening], 'available')
FROM
(
    SELECT  h.id, h.hallName, h.hallType, t.timeSlot,
            status = case when b.status in ('pending', 'confirmed') 
                          then 'Booked' 
                          when b.status in ('cancelled')
                          then 'unavailable'
                          when b.status in ('unavailable')
                          then b.status
                          else NULL
                          end
    FROM    Halls h 
            LEFT JOIN BookingData b  ON  b.hallId     = h.id 
                                     and b.beginDate  = @date
            OUTER APPLY
            (
                select timeSlot = 'morning'   where b.time in ('morning', 'full time')
                union all
                select timeSlot = 'afternoon' where b.time in ('afternoon', 'full time')
                union all
                select timeSlot = 'evening'   where b.time in ('evening', 'full time')
            ) t
) D
PIVOT
(
    MAX (status)
    FOR timeSlot in ( [morning], [afternoon], [evening] )
) P
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/JFGQ9rNL)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is overtly complicated due to the fact the table does not implement normalization properly for "combined halls." We will need to separate `Hall 4+5` using string operation and then store the extracted information somewhere. Here is the query that I could think off:

```
with
 composite_halls as
  (select *,
    substring(hallName, charindex(' ', hallName) + 1,
    charindex('+', hallName) - charindex(' ', hallName) - 1) as id1,
    right(hallName, len(hallName) - charindex('+', hallName)) as id2,
    (null) as id3
  from halls where charindex('+', hallName) > 0),
 singular_halls as
  (select *,
   (select ch.id2 from composite_halls as ch where ch.id1 = h.id) as id1,
   (select ch.id1 from composite_halls as ch where ch.id2 = h.id) as id2,
   (select ch.id from composite_halls as ch where ch.id1 = h.id or ch.id2 = h.id) as id3
  from halls as h where charindex('+', hallName) = 0),
 all_halls as (
  select * from singular_halls
  union
  select * from composite_halls),
 valid_bookings as (
  select * from bookings where status = 'confirmed'
        and beginDate >= '2022-09-26' and endDate <= '2022-09-26')
select *,
  (case when exists (
          select *
          from valid_bookings as vb
          where (time = 'morning' or time = 'full time')
             and (vb.hallId = h.id
              or (vb.hallId = h.id1 and h.id3 is null)
              or (vb.hallId = h.id2 and h.id3 is null)
              or vb.hallId = h.id3))
    then 'booked'
    else 'available'
    end) as morning
  from all_halls as h
```

You can try it on fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/baQyI1Y7

It looks somewhat detestable and I believe someone else can write shorter queries.

The query above uses 4 CTEs with 3 of them deals with extracting the `id`s of relevant "combined halls." `composite_halls` will extract the numbers from `hallName` and puts them into `id1` and `id2`. `singular_halls` will put its counterpart's id in either `id1` or `id2` and its composite in `id3`. `all_halls` merges the two result into one. `valid_bookings` filters `bookings` for given timeframe and only `confirmed` `bookings` are taken.

The next step, it checks if any `bookings`' `hallId` correspond to any of `id`, `id1`, `id2`, `id3` within the `all_halls` entries. So far it only handles `morning` bookings and only provide `booked` and `available` status. You can expand it to provide `unavailable` by adding more `case when` to specifically handle `id1` up to `id3`. You can handle `after noon` and `evening` can be done the same way by changing the `time` parameter within the `case when` clause.

I don't think the query above is performant enough for a live application. Especially the fact that we operate on row-by-row basis to extract the relevant halls from the "combined" one.

I believe things would be much easier should you normalize the table a bit more. I feel its like doing excel using TSQL which doesn't seem right.

Comment: Should I create a 3rd table for the Normalization or there is another way to get around? What do you think the best possible solution? I've tried to get hold of local Devs, but did not get any solution so far, Once one of the questions si solved, I'm sure the other way would folow suit

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ look, i don't expect it to work immediately on your database. given we have no clue how it actually looked like (the column definition and such). if you said one of the columns actually a `bigInt` you may need to `cast` the thing into it. please take a look at your question, it did not specify what the column are.. which is why [mcve] is important.

Comment: in regard to the 3rd table for normalization.. it could help with many things (including casting), but ultimately its your own call. the query above is just a duct tape at best.

Comment: I have tried and added `after noon`, `evening` in the [db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/U06GwTb6) at least it does the job but, I think you're concatinating  `hall name` & `hall Id` which kinda throw error at fisrt line (with) **Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint**  coz `hall Id` is of `bigInt` data type and `hall name` is `NVarchar(100)` data type. And if you check closely, `Hall 4` effects `Hall 6` Booking status which souldn't. Only `Hall 6` Booking status depends on Hall 4 & 5.

Comment: @Abdifatah fixed that a bug just now. after reading your first comment i realized. when i tried to simplify it, i broke something. sorry. but didn't you say, you allow `unavailable` to be said as `booked`?

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your help man. And sorry if wasn't clear enough, I tried my best

Comment: Yup, doesn't matter if its labeled as `booked` or `unavailable`

Comment: if you wanted for `unavailable`, the easiest way would be expanding that `else 'available'` by adding more `case when`with the `h.id3 is null` clauses.. but i do think the query will be even longer :(

Comment: but you didn't said where the query was broken at(what was cousing the error) or re-addedthe db-fiddle link

Comment: @Abdifatah check the edits to see what i did wrong.