# Check Hall Availability using Date range and Time slot

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have 2 tables `Halls` & `Bookings` with the following schema & sample data

```
CREATE TABLE Halls 
(
    id bigint PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), 
    hallName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    hallType varchar(255) NOT NULL, 
    numSeats int NOT NULL, 
    status varchar(255) NOT NULL
    combinedIds int,
)

INSERT INTO Halls 
VALUES 
    ('Hall 1', 'Normal', 500, 'active', NULL),
    ('Hall 2', 'VIP', 30, 'active', NULL),
    ('Hall 3', 'VVIP', 5, 'active', NULL),
    ('Hall 4', 'Normal', 60, 'active', 6),
    ('Hall 5', 'Normal', 80, 'active', 6),
    ('Hall 4+5', 'Normal', 140, 'active', NULL);
   
SELECT * FROM Halls;


CREATE TABLE Bookings 
(
    id bigint PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), 
    custId int NOT NULL,
    hallId int NOT NULL, 
    beginDate NVarChar(100), 
    endDate NVarChar(100) NOT NULL,
    time varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
    status varchar(100) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO Bookings 
VALUES 
  (1, 1, '2022-09-28', '2022-09-28', 'morning', 'confirmed'),
  (6, 4, '2022-09-28', '2022-09-29', 'evening', 'cancelled'),
  (4, 3, '2022-09-28', '2022-09-28', 'full time', 'pending'),
  (4, 6, '2022-09-28', '2022-09-28', 'morning', 'pending'),
  (9, 4, '2022-09-28', '2022-09-30', 'after noon', 'confirmed');

SELECT * FROM bookings;
```

Booking time slots are : "morning", "after noon", "evening" & "full time"

I have the above 2 tables and I want to validate incoming Bookings if an overlapping Bookings exist

in short, I want to check if any overlapping Bookings with `status!='cancelled'` exits for the date range(beginDate, endDate) & time slot before inserting

if we take in the above booking table with its sample data

- *Hall 1* should be available in 'after noon' & 'evening' time slots only
- *Hall 2* should be available in any time slot since it isn't ('morning', 'after noon', 'evening' OR 'full time')
- *Hall 3* should not be available at all since it's booked full time
- *Hall 4* should be available in morning & evening time slots

  **NOTE:** Evening is booked but cancelled, which means it's available to book again
- *Hall 5* should be available in any time slot('morning', 'after noon', 'evening' OR 'full time')
- *Hall 6* should be available in morning & evening time slots

  **NOTE:** Hall 6 is actually a combination of *Halls 4 & 5* which means in any given time slots & date ranges for which one or both of them is Booked, *Hall 6* should automatically be unavailable/booked

Here are some of my trials so far, without taking `Hall 6` scenario into consideration

```
DECLARE @hallId int = 1;
DECLARE @beginDate NVarChar(50) = '2022-09-28';
DECLARE @endDate NVarChar(50) = '2022-09-29';
DECLARE @time NVarChar(50) = 'full time';

SELECT * 
FROM Bookings b 
WHERE b.hallId = @hallId  
  AND b.status != 'cancelled' 
  AND beginDate <= @endDate 
  AND endDate >= @beginDate
  AND b.time IN (@time, 'full time')
```

This query returns nothing which means it's available to book `Hall 1` on `2022-09-28/29` in `full time` time slot, but then check the Bookings table, 'Hall 1' is actually booked on  2022-09-28 morning

AND If I put in the time slots for the `time column` as below

```
DECLARE @hallId int = 1;
DECLARE @beginDate NVarChar(50) = '2022-09-28';
DECLARE @endDate NVarChar(50) = '2022-09-29'; 
DECLARE @time NVarChar(50) = 'full time';

SELECT * 
FROM Bookings b 
WHERE b.hallId = @hallId  
  AND b.status != 'cancelled' 
  AND beginDate <= @endDate 
  AND endDate >= @beginDate
  AND b.time IN ('morning', 'after noon', 'evening', 'full time')
```

for any Hall that has an overlapping `beginDate` or `endDate` will be considered as `booked` regardless of time slot

I want something like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spBookings
    @id bigInt, 
    @hallId int, 
    @custId int,
    @beginDate NVarChar(50), 
    @endDate NVarChar(50), 
    @time NVarChar(50),
    @status NVarChar(50), 
    @msg NVarChar(200) OUT
AS
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Bookings b 
               WHERE b.hallId = @hallId  
                 AND b.status != 'cancelled' 
                 AND beginDate <= @endDate 
                 AND endDate >= @beginDate 
                 AND b.time IN (@time, 'full time'))
    BEGIN
        SET @msg = 'info|That date or time slot is booked, select a 
          different one'
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO Bookings (custId, hallId, beginDate, endDate, time, status)
        VALUES (@custId, @hallId, @beginDate, @endDate, @time, @status)

        SET @msg = 'success|Booking success'
    END
```

Here is a [db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ofb3e7X1) with the tables, their schema, sample data plus some more commented details

I posted this [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73847831/check-hall-booking-status) which was about **Halls Availability report** before and got advised to Normalize the `Halls` table for composite halls (hall 6).

I really appreciate whatever the best possible solution to get around this.

Comment: it's labeled as `morning` from 7AM to 12PM,   `after noon` from 1PM to 6PM,   `evening` from 7PM to 12AM. and `full time` is from 7AM to 12AM, it could be extended to 2AM but that does n't effect much in the booking time slots

Comment: You should be using the datetime datatype here instead of varchar. You are going to have to convert your string to a datetime anyway to check. Choosing the right datatypes is extremely important. Your column named time is poorly named for sure and needs some normalization. I would come up with a better name than time and probably move the values to a lookup table. That way if you need to change up stuff you simply change the lookup table instead of every row in your table.  I would do the with status, halltype, etc.

Comment: whoa whoa whoa, so.. the requi- finish line keeps moving and become more and more complicated. its very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73847831/check-hall-booking-status/) but now it has more seasonings. i felt wasting time working on the previous one. i do think you need to **rework** how your table will look like depends on the requirements. like those time constraint need to be stored somewhere, not in words.

Comment: what about if I add `combinedIds` which will hold `6` fro Hall 4 & Hall 5 & `Null` for the rest as @squirrel did in the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73847831/check-hall-booking-status), I mean that actually did the work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is similar to your earlier [Check Hall Booking status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73847831/check-hall-booking-status) question.

The basic concept is to find any matches of your input against the booking information. Not directly from the `Bookings` table but the exploded, taking into consideration of the `combinedIds`. And for this case, you are only interested in the `unavailable` status, you can filter out the `cancelled`

```
   select b.hallId, b.time, beginDate, endDate
   from   Bookings b
   where  b.status not in ('cancelled')

   union all

   select hallId = h.combinedIds, b.time, b.beginDate, b.endDate
   from   Bookings b
         inner join Halls h on b.hallId = h.id
   where  b.status not in ('cancelled')
   and    h.combinedIds is not null

   union all

   select hallId = h.id, b.time, b.beginDate, b.endDate
   from   Bookings b
          inner join Halls h on b.hallId = h.combinedIds
   and    h.combinedIds is not null
   where  h.combinedIds is not null
```

Next you need to translate `full time` into 3 rows of `morning`, `afternoon` (by the way it is spelled without a space in between), `evening`. You can do that with following query

```
select time = 'morning' where @time in ('morning', 'full time')
union all
select time = 'afternoon' where @time in ('afternoon', 'full time')
union all
select time = 'evening' where @time in ('evening', 'full time')
```

The above query are actually solution from your previous question.

Putting all together

```
SELECT *
FROM   
(
    select time = 'morning' where @time in ('morning', 'full time')
    union all
    select time = 'afternoon' where @time in ('afternoon', 'full time')
    union all
    select time = 'evening' where @time in ('evening', 'full time')
) t
INNER JOIN
(
       select b.hallId, b.time, beginDate, endDate
       from   Bookings b
       where  b.status not in ('cancelled')
  
       union all
  
       select hallId = h.combinedIds, b.time, b.beginDate, b.endDate
       from   Bookings b
             inner join Halls h on b.hallId = h.id
       where  b.status not in ('cancelled')
       and    h.combinedIds is not null
  
       union all
  
       select hallId = h.id, b.time, b.beginDate, b.endDate
       from   Bookings b
              inner join Halls h on b.hallId = h.combinedIds
       and    h.combinedIds is not null
       where  h.combinedIds is not null
) b ON t.time = b.time
WHERE b.hallId    = @hallId
AND   @beginDate <= b.endDate
AND   @endDate   >= b.beginDate
```

And incorporate that into your stored procedure

```
IF   EXISTS
     (
         < above query>
     )
BEGIN
   -- not available
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    -- insert into Bookings table
END
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/PITGqmNy)

Side Note :

Please use proper data type example for begin/end Date use `DATE` instead of nvarchar

Comment: Thank you man @Squirrel,   I really appreciate you. I knew & said the logic is same but with a little twist. This one is working fine except for `full time` (Halls Booked in `full time` slot can be Booked on `morning`, `afternoon` OR  `evening` time slots again (eg. Hall 3 can be Booked despite having `full time` Booking). I will figure out that part. Thank you once again

Comment: I forgot to expand the `full time` booking to 3 rows `morning`, `afternoon` & `evening` in the booking sub-query.  See your previous question, the `BookingData` sub-query does this

Comment: done with it and on to the next move. Thank you. and of course I'm using `date` data type now